# Converting C# Data Types from unknown sources

Tags: c#, types

There seems to be a lot of confusion around converting strings (usually) to their appropriate datatype, whilst validating it on the fly as well. Wherever I look - blogs, articles, code samples, forums.. a few people seem to have a ***preferred*** way of dealing with these scenarios.

The case is usually a string/object that comes from an unknown source, such as QueryString, Session/Viewstate, WebService, and so on...

**I've seen many different examples:**

Say we're trying to get the `id=` Query String and use it in our code as an integer. But someone tampered with our URL and changed it to

> http://www.example.com/page.aspx?id=sometextvalue

**One way**

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"]);
// "Input string was not in a correct format"
```

**Another way**

```
int id = (int)Request["id"];
// "Input string was not in a correct format"
```

**Yet another way**

```
int id = int.Parse(Request["id"]);
// "Input string was not in a correct format"
```

**I have ever seen this** *(And it kind of makes sense to throw an exception and notify the user)*

```
int id = 0;
try {
    id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"]);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    lblError.Text = ex.Message;
}
if(id > 0) { ... }
```

**Lastly, and the one I personally use**

```
int id = 0;
int.TryParse(Request["id"], out id);

// make sure it's not 0
if(id > 0) { // live a happy life }
```

This goes for all the other types, `bool`, `double`, `decimal` and so on..

Please help me understand what the correct way is, as I find myself using this on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: Right place for right thing. Thats why people are so excited about Ruby/Python! Concentrate on the behavior and data..types can be dealt with later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, for starters you should be using:

```
int id;
if(!int.TryParse(Request["id"], out id)
    //notify the user, or handle it someother way
```

instead of checking for id > 0. `int.TryParse(string, out int)` returns `true` if the parse succeeded, `false` otherwise.

[MSDN Documentation for int.TryParse(string, out int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @wawa, I didn't know TryParse returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

The `System.ComponentModel` namespace contains a well-designed framework for doing exactly these types of conversions.

Inspect the namespace for yourself, but this will get you going for starters:

```
targetType newValue = (targetType) System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetDescriptor(typeof(sourceType))
    .ConvertTo((object)value, typeof(targetType))
```

You get the basic type conversions for free in one centralized type-agnostic place rather than having to search through the unfortunately inconsistent X.Parse or X.TryParse methods found on the primitive types.

On top of the basics, you get an extensible framework where you can write your own type converters among other things. The ASP.NET MVC framework makes use of this namespace heavily to handle its type conversions for things like query-string value conversions to method parameters.

Comment: This looks really interesting @James, I'll try find some more information on it.

Comment: +1, I am sure it is just a typo, newValue should be of targetType and likewise the cast of the result of ConvertTo()

Comment: Should this be TypeDescriptor.GetConverter instead of TypeDescriptor.GetDescriptor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of these would actually be considered "Correct". I like to use Convert.ToInt32() because I can get some specific exceptions that I can check for to see if its valid input.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` generates the same exceptions as `int.Parse`.

Comment: And you should instead rely on boolean-returning TryParse methods since exceptions should not drive your program flow.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: Answer is, it depends. You should learn the difference between typecasting, parsing. Use them appropriately.

Comment: But there is no blanket answer to all of your scenarios.